# how to make a call from plsql oracle to form list of filenames in single lines present in unix directory

Tags: oracle, unix, plsql

I have a list of files lets say

```
File 1 : a_0001,
File 2 : b_1001,
File 3 : c_2001
```

present in

```
Directory : /home/swa/IBI directory.
```

I want to form an *oracle* string as below

```
" [a_001] [b_1001] [c_2001] "
```

and use this string for further oracle processing.

I cannot give any code here. As, I don't know any function which does this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question and add some additional information: what is the source of the list of file names (DB table?), sample input and expected output.

Comment: Please clarify: do you have a directory *on your database server* and want to get a list of its contents? Or do you have a directory *on your client* ?

Comment: Are you asking how to declare variables in plsql? oracle_string := '[a_001] [b_1001] [c_2001]' ? Or is it has to be created dynamically maybe? Try to ask proper question here ;)

Comment: @frank schmitt : Yes, the directory is on unix server and which is also database server. 
I want to a assign a plsql variable with value , filenames from unix variable. 

For example : I have files with filenames in directory a_0001, b_1001, c_2001.
I would want a plsql vairable with value 
for eg. merged_filename varchar2(200) := [a_0001][b_1001][c_2001];

Comment: @massko : 
There is a plsql vairable already present. I just want to assign the unix server filenames to the oracle variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since Oracle 11 you can use external table preprocessing to list files in directory and then iterate over files read from external table.

Something like here: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=513

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly oracle doesn't have function to list files in directory. For this you'll need to use java source. List files in directory, read input and create your variable. Here's java source which will execute commands in unix environment:

```
create or replace and compile java source named "Host" as
import java.io.*;
public class Host {
  public static void executeCommand(String command) {
    //String[] commands = command.split(" ");
    try {
      String[] finalCommand;
      /*if (isWindows()) {
        finalCommand = new String[4];
        // Use the appropriate path for your windows version.
        //finalCommand[0] = "C:\\winnt\\system32\\cmd.exe";    // Windows NT/2000
        finalCommand[0] = "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";    // Windows XP/2003
        //finalCommand[0] = "C:\\windows\\syswow64\\cmd.exe";  // Windows 64-bit
        finalCommand[1] = "/y";
        finalCommand[2] = "/c";
        finalCommand[3] = command;
      }
      else {
        //finalCommand = new String[commands.length + 2];
        finalCommand = new String[commands.length];
        //finalCommand[0] = "/bin/bash";
        //finalCommand[1] = "-c";
        //for (int i = 2; i < commands.length; i++){
        //  finalCommand[i] = command[i];
        //}
        for (int i = 0; i < commands.length; i++){
          finalCommand[i] = commands[i];
        }
      }*/

      //final Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(finalCommand);
      final Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.split(" "));
      pr.waitFor();

      new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
          BufferedReader br_in = null;
          try {
            br_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            String buff = null;
            while ((buff = br_in.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println("Process out :" + buff);
              try {Thread.sleep(10); } catch(Exception e) {}
            }
            br_in.close();
          }
          catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught printing process output.");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally {
            try {
              br_in.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {}
          }
        }
      }).start();

      new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
          BufferedReader br_err = null;
          try {
            br_err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));
            String buff = null;
            while ((buff = br_err.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println("Process err :" + buff);
              try {Thread.sleep(10); } catch(Exception e) {}
            }
            br_err.close();
          }
          catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught printing process error.");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally {
            try {
              br_err.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {}
          }
        }
      }).start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
  }

  public static boolean isWindows() {
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().indexOf("windows") != -1)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

};
```

PLSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE host_command (p_command  IN  VARCHAR2)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'Host.executeCommand (java.lang.String)';
```

Script:

```
DECLARE
  l_output DBMS_OUTPUT.chararr;
  l_lines  INTEGER := 1000;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.enable(1000000);
  DBMS_JAVA.set_output(1000000);

  host_command('printenv');
  --host_command('/bin/ls /home/oracle');

  DBMS_OUTPUT.get_lines(l_output, l_lines);

  FOR i IN 1 .. l_lines LOOP
    -- Do something with the line.
    -- Data in the collection - l_output(i)
    /*
      l_output(i) - unix / java output
      Parse files list here and make your variable:
    */
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_output(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is an C library / listener.ora / Library / External Function approach. It could be helpful on XE edition where there is not java**

Note: when there is an directory listing over 32000 chars this solution causes buffer overflow

1) Prepare Your shared C library (in list.c) - this is definitely not the safest & best solution on how-to code directory listing in C. But You got the basic idea.

```
//
// FILE: list.c
//
// gcc -Wall -fPIC -c list.c
// gcc -shared -o list.so list.o
// mkdir -p /u01/lib
// cp list.so /u01/lib
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

char *list_dir(const char *path) {

  char *filelist;
  filelist=(char *) calloc(32000,sizeof(char));

  struct dirent *entry;
  DIR *dir=opendir(path);

  if (dir==NULL) {
    return;
  }

  strcat(filelist,"");
  while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
    strcat(filelist,entry->d_name);
    strcat(filelist,"\n");
  }
  strcat(filelist,"\0");

  closedir(dir);

  return (filelist);
}
```

2) Edit Your LISTENER.ORA

```
...
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = <PATH TO ORACLE >)
      (ENVS="EXTPROC_DLLS=/u01/lib/list.so")
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This line enables calling of external libs
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
...
```

3) Prepare database objects

```
create or replace library c_list is '/u01/lib/list.so';
/

create or replace function host_list(v_directory in varchar2) return varchar2 as external
  name "list_dir"
  library c_list
  language c
  parameters (v_directory string, return string);
/
```

And finally use it with:

```
declare 
  v_ret varchar2(32000);
begin
  v_ret := host_list('/u01');
  dbms_output.put_line(v_ret);
end;
/
```

You can of course modify the both the C and the string post-processing to suit Your needs.

Best regards

P.S. You can translate the result to table as follows

```
create or replace package sysop as
  type file_list_rec is record(filename varchar2(1024));
  type file_list is table of file_list_rec;

  function ls(v_directory varchar2) return file_list pipelined;
end;
/

create or replace package body sysop as
  function ls(v_directory varchar2) return file_list pipelined is
    rec file_list_rec;
    v_host_list varchar2(32000) := '';
  begin    
    v_host_list := host_list(v_directory);

    for file in (
      select regexp_substr(v_host_list, '[^'||chr(10)||']+', 1, level) 
        from dual
          connect by 
            regexp_substr(v_host_list, '[^'||chr(10)||']+', 1, level) is not null)
      loop         
        pipe row (file);
      end loop;         
     return;
  end ls;
end sysop;
/
```

And use it like this:

```
select * from table(sysop.ls('/u01')) order by 1;
```